# When is it okay to use copy.deepcopy()?

Tags: python, coding-style, deep-copy

I'm working on a class that takes a certain number of images and performs different types of image operations on them. Images can be added to the class at any time to be modified by class methods. The images are stored by the class instance in a list. Many image operations require certain modes, so I'd like all of the images to be converted to the same mode. To accomplish this, I've written a wrapper that is applied to every image operation function. Whenever the function is called, the wrapper checks to see if the images list has changed, and, if it has, which images are new and need to be converted. I'm using deepcopy, but I understand that it's somewhat slow, so I'm wondering if my usage is appropriate, or if there is an alternative way to accomplish the same thing. Here's my code:

```
def _compwrapper(func):
    '''Checks to see if self.comp is defined before calling any image
    manipulation functions.'''

    def wrapped(self):
        if self.images: #if any images have been added
            if not self.oldimages: #if this isn't set, none have been converted
                self._convert(self.images)
                self.oldimages = copy.deepcopy(self.images)

            elif self.oldimages != self.images:
                diff = list(set(self.images) - set(self.oldimages))
                self._convert(diff)
                self.oldimages = copy.deepcopy(self.images)

            func(self)
        else:
            logging.info("Add some images before you try to do that!")

    return wrapped
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. This is my first 'serious' program in Python, so I'm trying to learn as much as I can about good practices as I can. If any further clarification is needed, let me know.

Comment: Why not just convert images on insertion?

Comment: @user2357112: I'd considered doing that, but the methods for adding the images aren't part of the class that's doing the manipulations. I don't want the 'retrieval' classes to have any methods that can modify the images (but the class that's modifying the images is subclassing the retrieval class). Does that make sense?